# ORA-03111 on WebLogic 12.1.2

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, weblogic12c, weblogic12g

During migration from OAS10 to WebLogic 12.1.2, a call to a stored procedure is producing an ORA-03111 around 4 minutes after it is invoked:

```
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-03111: break received on communication channel
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:462)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:931)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:213)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1488)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3770)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3955)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:9353)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1539)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:101)
at mycode.app.impliq.dao.connection.oracle.OracleProcesoDao.callSP(OracleProcesoDao.java:811)
```

This code is NOT using statement timeout and it is not configured at data source level either.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways from here.
1. check the connection pool settings in both weblogic and db for your data source.
2. check log running sql.